# How to merge PHP and HTML theme code?

Tags: php, html

For a school project I need to make a webshop. Right now the products are in a table, but I really dislike the look of it, because it looks very unprofessional. This is the code:

```
    while($product = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        echo "<form action=\"add_product.php\" method=\"post\">\n";
        echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"productnumber\" value=\"".$product['product_id']."\" />\n";
        echo "<p> <b>".$product['name'] . "</b> <br />\n";

        echo "<table>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo "<td>" . $product['image'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $product['description'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</table>";

        ?>


            <?php

                echo "Price: €".$product['price']."<br />\n";
        echo "Quantity: <input type=\"text\" name=\"Quantity\" size=\"2\" maxlength=\"2\" value=\"1\" />\n";
        echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Add To Cart\" /></p>\n";
        echo "</form>\n";
    }
}
?>
```

Now, from the template I'm using (Modus by Luis Zono) I want to make the products show up like this page: http://luiszuno.com/themes/modus/portfolio.html with this HTML code:

```
<div class="featured portfolio-list">
// This is one figure, but it can be copy-pasted to infinity:
                    <figure>
                        <a href="img/dummies/gallery-1.jpg" data-rel="prettyPhoto" class="thumb"><img src="img/dummies/gallery-1.jpg" alt="Alt text" /></a>
                        <div>
                            <a href="project.html" class="heading">Pellentesque habitant morbi</a>
                            tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. 
                        </div>
                        <a class="link" href="project.html"></a>
                    </figure>
<div class="clearfix"></div>

                </div>
```

My coding skills aren't very good, so how can I write code that makes the products in the loop look like the portfolio-figures? (so that the dummy image will be the $product['image'] and such). I'm totally stuck right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not going to give the answer (SO is not that kind of site), but the road how to get there.The example below is IMO the best solution here, but for your situation:
In php you can do this:

```
while($product = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    ?>
    <!-- Your code here -->
    <img src="example-html-image.jpg" />
    <!-- Your code here -->
    <?php
} // end of while
```

So, instead of the current echo of html you got now, you add the html you want.

You probaly want to use the fetched variables in your code, below I'll provide two examples:

```
while($product = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    ?>
    <!-- You can do this -->
    <img src="image<?php echo $product['id']; ?>.jpg" />

    <!-- Or the short version of echo -->
    <img src="image<?=$product['id'] ?>.jpg" />
    <?php
}
```

---

If you want to kick it up a notch, you should not use html in your code at all. The same way you dont use JS in-page, you dont use html in php. You use a template (**this is the most proper method IMO)**:

```
<!-- example.html: -->
<div> Hi, Im product <!-- NAME --> </div>
```

Very simple, and I use a comment to get replaced further along the line.

Then you take php, open the file, and replace the comment:

```
$template = file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'loc/to/file/example.html');
$template = str_replace("<!-- NAME -->", $product['name'], $template);
echo $template;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't just add an image because it is different for every product, right? That's what I'm struggling with.. I can't get the layout merged with the php because for every product it is different...  EDIT - Sorry, didn't see you edited your answer. I'll give it a try! (and I didn't downvote)

Comment: I've added that in my 2nd edit, that the middle part, see the `You probaly want to use the fetched variables in your code`-section

Comment: It works for the description and title! :D can't get the image to work yet though, neither with you method nor like this: <a href="<?php $product['image']; ?>" data-rel="prettyPhoto" class="thumb"><img src="<?php $product['image']; ?>"  alt="Alt text" /></a>

Comment: That is probaly because the url is not right. If you get the other items to work, this will to. Just use something like firebug or another console to see why the image doesnt load :)

Comment: @feroz, maybe we have to see what meta.exchange says about this :p Make it obligated to give a reason to downvote

Comment: there should be some popup to enter reason for down voting, it is really helpful for people who posted the answer and others

Comment: I just try to cancel them out by upvoting. But thats a whole other discussion. Mark this answer as solution if you think it is please :)

Comment: Guess it's just my noobyness that it ain't working.. So I'll mark it as answered and I'll just try stuff out to hopefully making it work. Still really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Assumed $product['image'] = "my_picture.jpg"

Then use this:

```
<img src="/path/to/images/<?php echo $product['image']; ?>" />
```

The result in html source will be:

```
<img src="/path/to/images/my_picture.jpg" />
```